# При подключении Bluetooth-динамика (JBL Flip 4) начинает тормозить интернет (Wi-Fi)

Tags: linux, wifi, linux-mint, bluetooth

При подключении Bluetooth-динамика (JBL Flip 4) начинает тормозить интернет (Wi-Fi).

ОС: Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa.

Comment: Оригинальная колонка?

Comment: ключевое слово: btcoex

Comment: @Aqua, да — оригинал.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, вроде как помогло, добавив в `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` следующее: `options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=1 swcrypto=1 11n_disable=8`, но еще проверяю.